# input display none fail?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I had a div that contained a few items. The first time i click the *Filter Button*, the div will show up. And the second time i click the button, the div will set to `display:none`.

Before Div set to `display:none`

[image]

The second time i clicked the filter button, it suppose to hide all the item inside the div...but these are the remaining

[image]

Code snippet:

```
 function ShowDivFilter() {

        if (document.getElementById("divFilter").style.display == "none") {
            $('div[id*="divFilter"]').attr("style", "visibility: visible; display: inline;");
        }
        else {
            $('div[id*="divFilter"]').attr("style", "visibility: hidden; display: none");
        }

    }

  <div id="divFilter" style="display:none;" >
            <table id="tblFilter">
                <tr>
                <td >
                    <b>Filter</b>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlElement" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlOperator" >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Equal" Value="=" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Less than or equal" Value="<=" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Larger than or equal" Value=">=" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Not equal" Value="<>"/>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFilter" ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnDoFilter" Text="Ok" class="NavBut"/> 
                    <input id="btnCloseFilter" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="return ClearFilter()" class="NavBut" />                        
                </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
  </div>
```

Any reason will cause the issue above? Is it something to do with my internet explorer?

Comment: Could you check that the buttons showing are really inside the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#divFilter').toggle();
```

This will work for you

Please Check [**Demo here**](http://jsbin.com/fihuqehi/1/)

Comment: Maybe would be better option use the `#` instead. `$('#divFilter').toggle();` anyway, I don't see a reason that this would work and the OP code don't. Maybe there's somethind underliying

Comment: You are right @frikinside i forget to post the code here from my demo thanks :)

Comment: You are right probably but i have added `1.9.1.min.js` in fiddle its working see